# Find what lines are covered in a run of Java code as in a Code Coverage tool

Tags: java, compilation, jvm, code-coverage

I just wanted to do a little hobby project that does code coverage like EMMA or JaCoCo. As a first step, is there any way to check just what line is being run by my JVM at any moment?

So for example, for code like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        if(s.nextInt() == 0) {
            System.out.println("Zero");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Some Value");
        }
    }
}
```

So for an input say 1, how do I get the following output::

```
1
Lines Covered:
0
1
2
3
4
6
7
8
9
10
```

Basically, everything except the print "Zero" line. Is there any way to programmatically do this? Can someone point me to any resource for it?

Comment: Emma and JaCoCo are both open source.

Comment: Coverage tools like EMMA and Cobertura use bytecode instrumentation to modify classes at runtime. Being opensource projects it may be easiest if you examine how they implement the coverage counters to get an idea of how to do it yourself or ask on their mailing lists for pointers.